# GetHashCode returning same Value for the different Bit Flag Enums

Tags: c#, enums, gethashcode, enum-flags

I have Flag type Enum with bitwise representation for each element as below

```
[DataContract]
[Flags]
public enum TestProduct : long
{
    [EnumMember]
    A1 = 0x1,
    [EnumMember]
    A2 = 0x2,
    [EnumMember]
    A3 = 0x4,
    [EnumMember]
    A4 = 0x8,
    [EnumMember]
    A5 = 0x40,
    [EnumMember]
    A6 =0x4000000000,
}
```

I Crated this as Flags Enum because I need to store the combination of this entries. The problem I am facing here, I do have a generic code to check the HasCode and then do some operation if HashCode is not zero.

Here in this case, I get same Has code value returned for elements A5 and A6 which is returned as 64 (binary value for 0x40).

And if I have a combination of A5 and A6, it gives me a hashcode of zero.
Can some one please advise how I can handle this situation to avoid getting zero value for this combination and why is that both giving same hash code as that of A5.

Below code shows how it is represented.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Hash Code for A5 is ");
    Console.WriteLine(Enums.TestProduct.A5.GetHashCode());
    Console.Write("Hash Code for A6 is ");
    Console.WriteLine(Enums.TestProduct.A6.GetHashCode());
    Console.Write("Hash Code for A6 | A5 is ");
    Console.WriteLine((Enums.TestProduct.A6 | Enums.TestProduct.A5).GetHashCode());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And Result for this is as below:
[image]

Comment: It's entirely valid for `GetHashCode` to return zero, or to return the same hash code for multiple values. It sounds like you need to change your "generic code" which is making invalid assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly valid for `GetHashCode` to return any value it likes for an enum value, as long as it always returns the same value.

Although it's implementation defined, I suspect the reason you are getting 64 for `A6` and 0 for `A6 | A5` is down to the implementation of `GetHashCode` for the `long` type. As `GetHashCode` needs to return an `int` (which is 32 bits) it is going to have to do some additional processing to hash a `long` (which is 64 bits).

If you look at the reference source implementation for [Long.GetHashCode](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/uint64.cs,87286238a1563792) you'll see that it exclusive-or's the upper 32 bits with the lower 32 bits. For `A6` which is `0x4000000000` this will be `0x40 | 0x00` which is `0x40` (64).

For `A6 | A5` you'll end up with `0x4000000040`, which when the upper 32 bits are xor'd with the lower 32 bits will be `0x40 | 0x40` which will give you 0.

Comment: @user2081126 - although it is implementation defined, I suspect if you use an `int` you will get the behavior you want.

Comment: Why does it matter so much that you are getting zero?

Comment: Why not just define a `None` enum value, set it to 0 and then check that you value doesn't equal `TestProduct.None` ?

Comment: If it's generic then checking for a hash code of 0 to mean something is asking for trouble as you can't infer that a hash of zero means anything.